# start my GUI application on ubuntu start up with sudo permission?

Tags: 14.04, c++

i am new to ubuntu .Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

1 - i want to start my GUI application on ubuntu start up.
2 - the GUI application needs SUDO permission . is there any way i can start my application without entering suso password and run my application.

thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what the GUI application should do and if it has cli options that could possibly do harmful stuff?

Comment: the gui application should start on start up of ubuntu or reboot ,the user who is going to user the application will not be friendly with the cli.

Comment: The (safety) issue is that you *could* add the application to the sudoers file, as one of the answers suggests, but if the application has cli options that could be harfmful, your system is vulanrable. Any code on your system could do harmful things without you knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command;

`visudo`

and add end of line;

`username ALL=NOPASSWD: <application>`

Try to run after the application of sudo or gksudo.

Answer (score 0):

We will have to add a `sudoer` rule for you.  You can do this by adding a sudo snippet in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory.  For example, for allowing your current user to run `/usr/sbin/gparted`, issue the following command:

```
echo $( whoami ) ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/gparted | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/mysudorule
```

At this point you can launch `sudo -i /usr/sbin/gparted` and it will launch with elevated privileges.  Since now you can launch the appplication as root, no questions asked, you can go to the `Startup Applications` program and add a new entry where you fill the command with `sudo -i /usr/sbin/gparted`.  Note that I have not tested this.  The `-i` tells it to fully log in as root.

All examples here use `/usr/sbin/gparted` because it's tool that requires root, and as such was easy to test.  Obviously, you'll need to use your own programs full path.

I know there is a discussion that you should never run `sudo` for a graphical program, but `gksu` is not installed by default, and `pkexec` asks a password regardless of the sudoers configuration.  My tests indicate that `sudo -i` just works fine for graphical applications.

Comment: tried this not working when i do sudo -i "Application path " the terminal displays a empty line .

Comment: and the GUI app doesn't start?  At all?  What is the program any way?

Comment: no the program doesn't start at all, it is a small program written in qt. which just takes input from user like name and age ...

Comment: So, you basically get a prompt `$`, an empty line and then a prompt `$` again?  I really have no idea.  I tested this with gparted (because that requires root).  I'm sorry, but I fear I can't help you further.